# How do i merge files to make an .apk file

Tags: android, apk

I want to merge some files to make an apk file because i modded a game but i can't find something to put together the files. There is nothing online to help me put together these files.

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](https://foellix.github.io/AMT/) is perfect for merging APK's. If you want more detailed help you have to explain your problem in more detail. What kind of files do you have, where did you get them from ...